# Adding a UITextField in a UITableview Basics

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I just started Xcode objective-c recently and right now I'm trying to create a tableview with textfields in them to type. Ive looked into other stack overflow questions but many are from 6-8 years ago and seem to have a wide rage of answers and extremely complex. Could someone help me with the basics of how I can insert a textfield in a table view and give me some advice. Thanks!

Comment: just drag and drop uitextfield in `UITableViewCell` through storyboard

Answer (score 1):

**Write this code in uitableview cell**

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
textField.delegate = self;  
[aCell.contentView addSubview:txt];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

1. Drag and drop a UITableView in to your view
2. Drag and drop a UITableViewCell into your table.
3. Drag and drop a UITextField (or any
   other UI component that you need)

I would suggest you to please refer tutorials for that like

1.https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/22-table-views-in-ios/lessons/8
2.https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

They have best tutorials with all steps you can easily do whatever you want.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: I have update answer with proper tutorial link. and apdating appcode link too for the same.

Comment: Welcome Calvin.

Comment: Hello @CalvinChang Please mark answer as a right if you got any help with this answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        /*
         *   Actually create a new cell (with an identifier so that it can be dequeued).
         */

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    /*
     *   Now that we have a cell we can configure it to display the data corresponding to
     *   this row/section
     */

    UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 30, 200, 40)];
    tf.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
    tf.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    tf.text=@"Hello World";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:tf];

    /* Now that the cell is configured we return it to the table view so that it can display it */

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cell. Add the textfield in it and use that in the table by registering the nib or class.